# NoClassDefFoundError using elasticsearch in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to use elasticsearch in my java application but when I try to connect to my Node, i had the following error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/util/Version`

So I install the lucene librairie (version 6.5.1) And I still the error.
I'm a beginner with elasticsearch so please tell me if I forgot a step

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Mocky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3211/mocky) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java/34419#34419):

> This is caused when there is a class file that your code depends on
> and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Look for
> differences in your build time and runtime classpaths.

So, if using maven then add,

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
   <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

if using gradle,

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core

```
compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-core', version: '3.6.0'
```

Comment: Im on the IDE netbeans. I already add the `lucene-core-3.6.0.jar` librairie on my project. But It still didn't work, I got this error now :  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_3_6`